# How to prevent to step into node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

How to prevent to step into node_modules/*.js files when debugging the typescript project files in vs code editor. When I start a debug process with a berakpoint on my typescipt file, I want to step over js 
files under node_modules directory automatically.

**// my launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [ {
      "name": "LaunchChrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "trace": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
       "runtimeArgs": [ "--disable-web-security"]
    } ]
}
```

Comment: place a `debugger` at that place since it is a js file.

Comment: The funny thing, I want [the opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78064447/no-way-to-step-into-node-modules-anymore).

Answer (score 14):

Add the following to your launch.json...

```
"skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js"
]
```

From the sound of your question, you may also want to exclude the following...

```
"skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
]
```

Which then also excludes [node internal files](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib) (net.js, events.js, etc) if you wish.

Via documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code-node-chrome)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... the "skipFiles" would be a peer for "configurations" & "version"

Comment: From the docs, it's worth noting: `If you step into a skipped file, you won't stop there - you will stop on the next executed line that is not in a skipped file.`. This is a bit of a pain, and I havent found any way around it.