# Can Chrome Debugger exclude node_modules files?

Tags: angular, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging through an Angular 5 application in the Chrome Debugger. Skipping through the core.js, zone.js and observable files can become cumbersome. Are there any fancy tips or tricks for excluding those files from my debugging?

Comment: this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753631

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/settings/ignore-list

Answer (score 6):

open the dev tools settings, then the **Blackboxing** tab

then enter a pattern to match the files you need to ignore

Answer (score 4):

The Blackboxing tab has now been renamed in the latest Chrome and can be found  by Pressing `F1`

The Ignore list tab:
[image]

You may try a pattern of `webpack:///./node_modules`

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: The pattern is a regex. So, this worked for me: `.*node_modules.*`

Answer (score 1):

Now with the latest version of chrome, On **Developer Tools** > **Settings** *(Cog Icon ⚙️)* > **Ignore List**, **node_modules** files already ignored *by default*:

[image]