# Can i skip node internal modules in nodejs debugging while using visual studio code?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, node-modules, vscode-debugger

When im debugging a nodejs project, sometimes it just jump into the internal modules, "path.js helper.js loader.js util.js validator.js..."

1. How can i just skip from jump into those files while debugging?
2. Where are those file in my windows 10? i cant find such *.js file in 'C:\Program Files\nodejs'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753631/how-to-prevent-to-step-into-node-modules/45500506#45500506 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556495/how-do-i-skip-external-code-when-debugging-in-vs-code/47566410#47566410 and links therein.  Those modules like `path.js` are built into vscode "Built-in core modules of Node.js can be referred to by the 'magic name' <node_internals> in a glob pattern. " and would not be stored in the usual node_modules folder but somewhere in vscode's code.

Comment: thank you  Mark , I really appreciate your answer

Comment: You are welcome.