# No way to step into node_modules anymore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, node-modules

Is it just me, or Chromium DevTools stopped to stop at breakpoints in `node_modules` (including `/usr/lib/node_modules`)?

`a.js`:

```
console.log('a.js');
require('./b');
```

`b.js`:

```
debugger
console.log('b.js');
require('userhome');
```

```
$ npm i userhome@1.0.0
// add the following lines to node_modules/userhome/index.js:
// debugger
// console.log('userhome');
$ node --inspect-brk a.js
```

Open `about:inspect` in Chromium. Choose the process under Remote Target. Press F8. It stops at `b.js`. Press F8 again. It doesn't stop at `node_modules/userhome/index.js` and finishes.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to debug this issue somehow (a way to figure out why it doesn't stop at `node_modules` breakpoints)?

I'm running Chromium 121.0.6167.184 and nodejs v21.6.1.

**UPD** I just checked on another machine with Chromium 115.0.5790.102 and v20.4.0, and here it works. It had the Node.js V8 --inspector Manager (NiM) extension installed, but I turned it off before testing.

It looks as if `node_modules` is considered ["uninteresting"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code) in the recent versions of Chromium (and likely Chrome), and as such skipped. I'd like to disable it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I've found is... to not use Chromium DevTools. You can debug code with `vscode`:

- Launch it
- Ctrl-Shift-P
- Choose Debug: Attach to Node Process
- Choose the `node --inspect` process

The trick is, you [can't debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206683) processes running under `root`, as might be the case with processes running in `docker` containers.

**UPD** With the help of the `lscr.io/linuxserver/chromium` image I was able to figure out that it stopped working in Chromium around 120:

```
// 119.0.6045.159 +
$ docker run --rm --network=host \
  lscr.io/linuxserver/chromium:5098d7ca-ls46

// 120.0.6099.129 -
$ docker run --rm --network=host \
  lscr.io/linuxserver/chromium:4fed82c2-ls47
```

And I soon was able to find in What's new that they added [`node_modules`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-120#default-regex) to the [ignore list](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40938257).

Answer (score 1):

This is [a new feature in Chrome 120](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-120#ignore-listing), it does "*now skip scripts from `/node_modules/` and `/bower_components/` by default.*".

You can turn this off, or remove individual modules from that list, in the [*Ingore List* settings of the devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/settings/ignore-list).